# Is it possible to set a breakpoint in AVR Studio in files other than the one where the main() function is?

Tags: avr, debugging

If I have a project with more than one translation unit, AVR Studio only allows me to set breakpoints in the main c file.

It doesn't matter if I include the other files directly by `#include "something.c"` or by using their header.

A quick search on various embedded forums didn't result in any answer or even discussion regarding this topic. Is everyone using a single translation unit when debugging, or did I miss a feature in plain sight?

The project was generated by CodeVision, if it is of any relevance.

Comment: Check this http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/atmelstudio/ch05s07s02s01.html.

Comment: I seem to remember having a few similar hassles with AVR Studio but debugging seems a lot better under Atmel Studio. Any reason not to use that or were you just referring to it by the old name?

Comment: @PeterJ : I still need AVR Studio because Atmel Studio doesn't seem to work properly with some of my drivers (and it also lacks a feature which I need to use often in AVR Studio)

Comment: @Lazar : This is how I set the breakpoints in the main file. However, it doesn't work in other files.

Comment: If you change a piece of the code that is not in the main.c, compile and reprogram, does the new code get executed ? It's to see if "something.c" is being seen my the compiler. From what I remember ( a year ago), I didn't have any issues with breakpoints in files outside main.c

Comment: @efox29 : yes, it is. I made sure that the code I wish to place a breakpoint on is actually executed.

Comment: @vsz what debugger are you using ? does it have software or hardware breakpoints ? If you have both, can you switch between hardware and software ?

Comment: @efox29 : I use an AVR Dragon. Can the debugger have an effect on this feature? Thank you for mentioning the issue of software vs hardware breakpoints, because indeed, the chip I'm using (atmega168) doesn't seem to have hardware breakpoints. Maybe AVR Studio allows software breakpoints only in the main file? Sadly, this seems to be not well documented. I've found no list of which processors have how many hardware breakpoints, or if there is a difference in debuggers in this regard. Even the Atmel homepage doesn't list it as an element in their product finder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AVR. How do you specify the breakpoint? By line number? What actually happens if you try to set the breakpoint in another file? Is there some option in the compiler where you have to specify that in each module you have to include debug information when compiling each module? Maybe the separate modules are compiled without debug information? (Like the -g option in the gcc compiler for C in Linux)

Comment: I see that it is actually gcc being used. To enable debugging in modules, each module has to be compiled with the -g option. Mind that if you add -g, that by itself doesn't cause recompilation. You probably have to 'clean' (remove object files) to force recompiling all parts.

Comment: @jcoppens Why do you think gcc is being used, when I explicitly specified otherwise?

Comment: I was reading the AVR studio pages, and it mentions gcc often. And I was sure that Codevision's main tool was the integration. Well, I've learned since then that there are quite a few discussions about gcc vs Codevision's compiler. I stand corrected! But, it seems gcc/gdb can debug in all modules. I'd suggest you write CodeVision and ask them about the debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

It doesn't matter if the is in the main C file or not, if there is one path in the function  call tree *(which obviously has main at its root)* where control passes the line, you should be able to set a breakpoint on it.

I use a JTAG debugger and in the debugger software I load an ELF file that links functions and variables in code to addresses in the HEX file. So if you are not able to debug through code, verify if you have something similar, and if yes, verify that it is generated properly.

Or you may have a different problem altogether. Some of your files may not be included in the compilation. Check your build log to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the other files in your project. As source files. Including them as #include, or their headers, doesn't work.

If you are including them with #include, you have a single translation unit. You need to set them up as multiple translation units to get break points to work.

All recent versions of GCC include smart-linker workarounds ( --combine-fwhole-program ) that are intended to be an alternative method of creating a single translation unit (single-translation unit programs are generally smaller and faster). You need to create your own make file to do that. I haven't tried using the debugger: it might work (because the IDE includes all the source files in the "source file" branch, or it might not work (because the IDE can't follow how the source files were linked).

Comment: I would, gladly, if only AVR Studio allowed me to add files manually to the COF.

Comment: COF ?? COFF ??.  If you want the IDE to follow the source code to a break point, you need to load the source code in a way that the IDE understands. Right Click on Source Files.

Comment: I use the COF file generated by the compiler to load the project. If I right click on "Source Files" in AVR Studio, it doesn't allow me to add any files.

Comment: So, don't do that. Create a new project, load the source files. Build obj, map, and elf files. But Perhaps if you build an ELF file instead of COFF, it will include sufficient information to allow the IDE to identify other source files.